# Is it possible to improve the pngquant output in this case?

Tags: png

Here is part of the original image

[image]

Here is the output from `pnqguant` with quality set to 50.

[image]

You can see the artefacts in the shadow area of the compressed image is very prominent.

Is there any pngquant parameters I can tweak to improve the visual quality

Answer (score 0):

Here are tips that helped me resolve the same exact issue:

1. Make sure you use version 2 of pngquant, on their website they have [good comparisons of version 2 vs photoshop 'Save for web' feature](https://pngquant.org/vsphotoshop.html). Shadows are perfect there.
2. Make sure you use `--speed` parameter (I've found that setting it to slowest value `1` gave me the most perfect shadow), and by default they don't use the slowest option.
3. Make sure you play with all possible values `--quality`, finding the most optimal tradeoff between shadow quality and image size.